# Why does it write to 2 lines in a text file when I only ask it to type 1?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Basically I need to write a line to a txt file containing details about a product, these details are from another text file which I split. The final detail which is the quantity variable is an inputted number.

```
document = open('Task2.txt', 'r')
strquantity = str(quantity)
for line in document:
    the_line = line.split(",")
    if the_line[0] == GTIN:
        with open("receipt.txt", "a") as receipt:
            receipt.write(the_line[0] + "," + the_line[1]+ "," +the_line[2] + "," + strquantity)
document.close()
```

The task 2 file contains:

```
12345670,spatula,0.99
57954363,car,1000.20
09499997,towel,1.20
```

The quantity number is 5 and the GTIN number is 12345670. The line it should write to the file is:

```
12345670,spatula,0.99,5
```

But instead it writes:

```
12345670,spatula,0.99,
5
```

(no line space (five on the next line under))

Why does it do this and how do I make it so it just writes to the 1 line? Thanks.

Comment: Please properly format your code by indenting each line 4 spaces. This is unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because when you read in each line, it will have a newline at the end. So when you call `split`, the final entry will also contain a newline, so when you write `the_list[2]` it will split the line at this point. To get around this, call `strip()` to remove the newline as follows:

```
with open('Task2.txt', 'r') as document, open("receipt.txt", "a") as receipt:
    strquantity = str(quantity)

    for line in document:
        the_line = line.strip().split(",")

        if the_line[0] == GTIN:
            receipt.write(','.join(the_line[0], the_line[1], the_line[2], strquantity) + '\n')
```

Comment: Almost... I think you meant `line.strip().split(",")`. As it is your code will attempt to call the non-existent `list.strip()`  method.

Comment: Well spotted. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

you need to trim the newline character from each line just before exploding it.

```
the_line=line.strip()
the_line=the_line.split(",")
```